# Unexpected token ":" in query modifier

Tags: javascript, json, express, sails.js

I am using sailsjs for my api project. According to the documentation http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models following query modifier may be used

```
User.find({
  or: [
    name: { startsWith: 'thelas' },
    email: { startsWith: 'thelas' }
  ]
}, cb);
```

So based on this I build following modifier:

```
var query = {
    or: [
        cityName: {
            contains: req.param('city')
        },
        zoneNumber: {
            startsWith: req.param('query')
        }
    ]
};
```

And I pass it like this

```
User.find(query, function(err, res){});
```

However I get an error regarding the query format:

```
cityName: {
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Does my query break json format rules? Or is this a not common error comming from the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = {
    or: [{
        cityName: {
            contains: req.param('city')
        },
        zoneNumber: {
            startsWith: req.param('query')
        }
    }]
};
```

You are missing `{}`